# Add dynamically generated columns to django admin list view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

**Backgorund**

I have these two models:

```
TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (0, 'Income'),
    (1, 'Outcome'),
)

class Transaction(models.Model):
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    store = ForeignKey(Store)

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=300)
    balance = models.ForeignKey(Transaction)
```

**What I need to achieve**

Currently, django shows this output in Admin list view for model Movements (assuming we have two stores):

```
Type     Amount  Store
------------------------
Income   100     Store A
Outcome  20      Store A
Income   500     Store B
```

I'd like to show custom columns, each showing partial balance for a store:

```
Type     Amount  Store    Store A Balance  Store B Balance
----------------------------------------------------------
Income   100     Store A  100              0
Outcome  20      Store A  80               0
Income   500     Store B  80               500
```

I know how to make a custom static column and I know how to calculate the values for the rows, but I can't figure out how to make the columns dynamic, i.e. to show in accordance with another model.

**PS**: Please, note that the number/names of stores may change. If I add a new store, the partial balance for that store should be shown in the list view too.

Answer (score 0):

When adding a model to admin you can show methods from your admin class as columns of the list:

```
class AdminTransaction(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('type', 'amount', 'store', 'dynamic')

    def dynamic(self, obj):
       # obj here is the object in this row of the list.
       # Lets say you want to show the difference between the amount of
       # the current transaction and the maximum amount is known then:
       maximum_known = AdminTransaction.objects.aggregate(max_amount=MAX('amount'))
       return maximum_known['max_amount'] - obj.amount
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: Sorry, but with this method I can't add a dynamic number of columns or specify their names with data from another model. Thank you for the answer!